# Triggers executions Check repository

Tags: jenkins, scheduled-tasks, cloudbees

I want to have a trigger to see if there are any changes in the SVN every night from Monday to Friday at 22:00. I understand that I must put the following syntax "H 22 ** 1-5" is this correct?

At the root of this I have a question:

The company is in Spain, then what time is 22:00 Spanish or American?

Thank you very much and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your timezone by logging into your instance and then going to JENKINS_URL/configure (Global properties).